# How do you implement a copy constructor when an element doesn't persist in your class?

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

for example, your constructor might look like this:

```
myClass::myClass(Mesh &mesh) : baseClass(mesh) 
{
    pointer = new Thing(mesh);
}
```

mesh is not held in myClass, nor is there a getter for mesh in baseClass where it is held. Is this simply a case of having to implement a getter in the base class?

for example you cannot do this:

```
myClass::myClass(const myClass& original) : baseClass(mesh) //there is no mesh
{
    pointer = new Thing(mesh); //mesh is no longer in the parameter list
}
```

How does the compiler make this copy when it creates a default copy constructor for such classes? Or is this a case where a copy constructor is necessary? mesh is not a private member of brain, and there is not getter for it so how do we make a new Thing?

**EDIT - Updated the problem by adding `Thing`**

Comment: It's usually a mistake to try. Think carefully about why, for example, `fstream` instances cannot be copied.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`mesh` has to be copied inside the `baseClass` copy constructor.

```
class baseClass
{
  Mesh myMesh;
public:
  baseClass(const baseClass &other) : myMesh(other.myMesh) {} // <--- copy Mesh
};

class myClass : public baseClass
{
public:
  myClass(const myClass& other) : baseClass(other) {} // <--- simply pass
};
```

Comment: "mesh is not held in myClass" - I assume he means that `mesh` is a member of reference type in his existing implementation.

Comment: it means it's just being passed through the constructor to the base class. There is no getter in the base class.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel, the question says that `... getter for mesh in baseClass where it is held`, which means `mesh` is held in baseClass. It is not mentioned if it's a reference or pointer.

Comment: @SirYakalot, for copy construction, you don't need any getter method. See the code in my answer. If `mesh` is a member of `baseClass` then that's how you would copy it.

Comment: @SirYakalot, move the line `pointer = new Thing(mesh);` to the `baseClass` copy constructor.

Answer (score 3):

Every class will have to take care of its own copying.

The default copy constructor for myClass will simply call the copy constructor for the base class (and for every other member).

Comment: I just updated the question with an extra component. How would you go about creating a new `Thing` in the copy constructor?

Comment: also, MUST the base class of a class that has a copy constructor implement one? Or would it be enough to just to call the constructor in some cases.

Comment: The default copy constructor will copy all members of a class (a shallow copy). A copied pointer will then point to the same object as the original. If this is ok, you can use the compiler generated copy constructor. If this is not what you want, you will have to create your own copy constructor, perhaps using code like `pointer = new Thing(*(original.mesh));`.

Answer (score 1):

The cannonic copy constructor would be:

```
MyClass::MyClass( MyClass const& other )
    :  BaseClass( other )
{
}
```

The copy constructor for `BaseClass` would take a const reference to
`BaseClass`, and `other` would convert implicitly.  The copy constructor
for `BaseClass` would then do whatever was necessary.

This is the implicitly generated constructor, so you don't have to
provide it, provided you're happy with the other aspects of generated
constructors: public and inline.